# Restrict access of subdirectory PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have multiple directories in my hosting directory. Let's say

```
dir_A
dir_B
dir_C
```

I created FTP account for each directory, so user of each directory can't access other dirs ( user of dir_A can't access dir_B, etc.)

But I realize that with PHP you can just run readdir and get the content of any file/dir unless Unix permissions restrict that. I did some search and found that perhaps I need to set basedir in my php.ini settings, but I don't know how. This is a shared hosting account and I can't modify system php.ini. Can I put php.ini or user.ini in subdirectory and solve this problem ? I don't have time to learn php.ini at this moment so please don't send me links to learn it ( I will when I have time ). Please provide an example.

I understand that even with php.ini, I will restrict access just to php files, but I guess that's enough if there is no higher level flag.

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has no knowledge of who is allowed what.  Any php scripts will be run as the web server, which means that every php script must be trusted with the web server's permissions.  In other words, if you give someone permission to upload php files to a server to be executed, you are trusting them with access to it. NOTE: This also means you are trusting them to not upload anything with a security flaw, because your whole server is as secure as the least secure thing anybody uploaded.

Comment: The option open_basedir (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir), will only prevent PHP to read outside of the root directory of the app, but anything inside the app root will still be accessible.

Comment: I understand that and also I mentioned that it doesn't matter if it is php or not. Just wanted to know what is the common practice. Looks like it is not common and/or not possible to do this.

Comment: I just want to create like a mini bubble directory, so other people can work there but not outside.